# How to check if a thread is busy in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a Windows Forms UI running on a thread, `Thread1`. I have another thread, `Thread2`, that gets tons of data via external events that needs to update the Windows UI. (It actually updates multiple UI threads.)

I have a third thread, `Thread3`, that I use as a buffer thread between `Thread1` and `Thread2` so that `Thread2` can continue to update other threads (via the same method).

My buffer thread, `Thread3`, looks like this:

```
public class ThreadBuffer
{
    public ThreadBuffer(frmUI form, CustomArgs e)
    {
        form.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { form.UpdateUI(e); });
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is for my `ThreadBuffer` to check whether my form is currently busy doing previous updates. If it is, I'd like for it to wait until it frees up and then invoke the `UpdateUI(e)`.

I was thinking about either:

a)

```
//PseudoCode

while(form==busy)
{
    // Do nothing;
}
form.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { form.UpdateUI(e); });
```

How would I check the `form==busy`? Also, I am not sure that this is a good approach.

b) Create an event in form1 that will notify the `ThreadBuffer` that it is ready to process.

```
// psuedocode

List<CustomArgs> elist = new List<CustomArgs>();

public ThreadBuffer(frmUI form, CustomArgs e)
{
    from.OnFreedUp += from_OnFreedUp();
    elist.Add(e);
}

private form_OnFreedUp()
{
    if (elist.count == 0)
        return;
    form.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { form.UpdateUI(elist[0]); });
    elist.Remove(elist[0]);
}
```

In this case, how would I write an event that will notify that the form is free?

and

c)  an other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There is an event that you might look at

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Idle
```

Answer (score 2):

> How would I check the form==busy ? Also, I am not sure that this is a good approach

`Control.Invoke` effectively does this already. There is no reason to "wait until the thread is not busy", as the Invoke call will not return until the method processes, which won't happen until the thread is not busy.

You can just call `Invoke` and not worry about whether the UI thread is busy.

Comment: So would the incoming events into the `BufferThread` be queued until the form frees up?

Comment: @Sam Yes.  Control.Invoke (and BeginInvoke) work by adding a message to the windows message queue.  The UI thread processes those messages (in order) as it can, so they'll just queue up and process when it gets a chance.

Comment: Understood. But what will happend if the user closes the form (its not on a main thread) - if i add: `if(form != null) form.Invoke....`  would that be sufficient?

Comment: @Sam I'd never be null (since you're keeping a reference).  You could check form.Visible, though...

Comment: This approach is fine for debugging. I use Invoke. But for an unknown reason it has started not to do anything. My guess is its blocked by control thread being busy. Blah blah blah. I need to find out what is happening and how to fix it. So long story short: The question is good, the answer is not! There are many (even good) reasons to do some silly things.